# How to use sans-serif fonts in Tikz and Rmarkdown?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, knitr, markdown

I cannot seem to control graphics fonts as expected when knitting to PDF from Rmarkdown. In researching the question, I found many recommended solutions which boil down to:

1. *Declare a document default and Tikz will use that* or

   2. *Tikz uses whatever you tell it to use in the document header.*

   Unfortunately, neither statement is true when it comes to Rmarkdown knit to pdf in RStudio.

I created something like a solution below but first, here is a list of header-based solutions that don't work:

```
--1--
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
--2--
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}  
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\pgfplotsset{
tick label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
every axis label = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
legend style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily},
label style = {font=\sansmath\sffamily}
}
--3--
\usepackage[eulergreek]{sansmath}  
\DeclareFloatFont{henry}{\sffamily\sansmath}
\floatsetup[figure]{font=henry}
--4--
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup{font={sf}}
```

Can anyone explain why none of these solutions work?

Here is a MWE and the partial solution I scrabbled together after reading the beautiful but technical [TikzDevice Guidebook](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/vignettes/tikzDevice.pdf):

````
---
output:
pdf_document:
latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
- \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,
dev = 'tikz')
library(tikzDevice)
```
# Tikz might not display sans-serif fonts...
...even when declared as the document default.

```{r }
plot(runif(20))
```

## Sans-serif fonts are tardy to the party

```{r t}
###################
## THIS WORKS!!! ##
###################
options(tikzLatexPackages = c(getOption("tikzLatexPackages"),
c("\\renewcommand{\\familydefault}{\\sfdefault}")))
###################
## see above     ##
###################
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=hwy, fill=factor(cyl)))+
geom_violin(scale = "width")
```
````

My purpose is to avoid hacky solutions like the one I provided above. **My question is this: Why don't the many much more convenient solutions (provided) work?**

I know it is a small thing but hopefully this can save someone else from unnecessary frustration.

Comment: Thank you for your response and sorry for not being more clear. My purpose is to avoid hacky solutions like the one I provided above. **My question is this: Why do the many much more convenient solutions I provided not work? Is it possible that this is a bug in the tikz device, as it seems not to check the document default as expected?

Comment: I use a custom class which set the the main document font to sans serif. I use the document declaration option to use the class and clear all package options. I also always use standAlone picitures, compiled to PDF to be included. It's easier and that way in my opinion. I am not sure if that solution still works, since I have changed to use serif fonts in figures now. There are just no good sans serif math fonts out there and mixing sans serif text and math together some time don't look good

Comment: Hi Yan Zhou! Are you saying you create your graphics separately when you compile your papers using knitr in R-Studio?